# When I try to profile large query I only get aggregate results, how to profile query parts?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I try to profile large query I only get aggregate results. How can I profile query parts? Sometimes I get an an error during execution of my `PROFILE` query.

Can I somehow get at least part of the results if I can't get the whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I would advise you to remove part of the query and profile only the relevant part or to profile one part at the time. I can see that this issue [has been reported to Memgraph](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/222) developers already.